# Is there any way to track the UK EEA Family Member Residence Card?

Tags: united-kingdom, family, residence-cards

I want to ask if there is any way to track UK EEA Family Member Residence card. I am worry about the application of my wife because we sent the documents 2 months ago and I read in internet that the biometric letter generally arrives at maximum one month after the payment is taken (I read the processing times of many people in many boards).

We talked with a friend and she delivered the documents in March, an email arrived her in May saying that they have her documents, after another month (in June) she received the Biometric letter, and two weeks ago (July), the COA letter arrived to her. It means that she had to wait for 4 months to get the COA. **Is it normal?**

She couldn't work for 2 months because she didn't have any document and neither the COA letter.

Do you know if there is a way to track the UK EEA Family Member Residence Card?

Can I call someone to ask for the status of my application?

Do you think the case of my friend is special? Because her passport expires in December of this year and it suppose that she will get the residence card in November, maybe for that it takes so long.

Do you know why in this period the COA letter for the EEA Family Member Residence Card are taking so long?

Answer (score 3):

I found that the times for the resident card are now longer. I don't know if it is normal, but I think that maybe the problem is the amount of requests due to the Brexit is increased.

You can call to the Home Office: 0300 123 2241 but probably they will say only that your case is being processed.

If the Home Office send you a letter or an E-mail, they always give an ID. This ID can be used to track the application in this page:

https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk